# How to literally create objects using 'usual' JavaScript syntax?

Tags: javascript

I am reading a book(I am new to JavaScript) and I'm just curious if it's possible to create objects using object literal notation declaration but to be able to use 'usual' JavaScript syntax and execute code in the declaration of this object, let me explain more in detail:

Simplest way to create an object is by using object literal notation declaration, like this(feel free to correct me if I'm wrong):

```
var chevy = {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Bel Air",
    year: 1957,
    color: "red",
    passengers: 2,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 1021,
    started: false,
    start: function() {
      this.started = true;
    }
};
```

What I don't like about this is syntax: colons instead of equal sings, commas instead of semicolons and limitations: inability to drop code in between lines, like this:

```
var chevy = {
    make: "Chevy",
    model: "Bel Air",
    year: 1957,
    color: "red",
    passengers: 2,

    **invokeFunction()**,

    convertible: false,
    mileage: 1021,
    started: false,
    start: function() {
      this.started = true;
    }
};
```

At some point of time I've stumbled(in HeadFirst JavaScript book) at this brain twister:

```
(function(food) {
    if (food === "cookies") {
      alert("More please");
    } else if (food === "cake") {
      alert("Yum yum");
    }
})("cookies");
```

Code above immediately invokes this anonymous function expression with "cookies" attribute. So after learning basics of functions, object literals and constructors it came to my mind that I can mix it to achieve 'usual' JavaScript syntax(for creating objects using object literal) using this trick(it works but doesn't look pretty):

```
var chevy = (function() {
    var _this = {};

    _this.make = "Chevy";
    _this.model = "Bel Air";
    _this.year = 1957;
    _this.color = "red";
    _this.passengers = 2;

    invokeFunction();

    _this.convertible: false;
    _this.mileage = 1021;
    _this.started = false;
    _this.start = function () {
        this.started = true;
    };
    return _this;
})();
```

But this is kinda a hack. What I'm trying to achieve here is a **'proper'** implementation of it, something like this(I know, code down below is wrong):

```
var chevy = {
    function callThisMethodWhenObjectIsCreated() {
        this.make = "Chevy";
        this.model = "Bel Air";
        this.year = 1957;
        this.color = "red";
        this.passengers = 2;

        invokeFunction();

        this.convertible = false;
        this.mileage = 1021;
        this.started = false;
        this.start = function () {
            this.started = true;
        };
    }
};
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to create object literals but using 'usual' JavaScript syntax or using constructor-alike method. <strike>Is that possible to call a method when object is created without using new operator?..</strike> At this point I just realized that I can literally create objects using a constructor and anonymous function:

```
var chevy = new (function() {
    this.make = "Chevy";
    this.model = "Bel Air";
    this.year = 1957;
    this.color = "red";
    this.passengers = 2;

    invokeFunction();

    this.convertible= false;
    this.mileage = 1021;
    this.started = false;
    this.start = function () {
      this.started = true;
    };
})();
```

This method(in my humble opinion) is better to literally create objects than to use object literal notation {}, it doesn't have its limitation(like inability to just drop code inside it) and you don't have to switch syntax between {} and usual syntax of JavaScript.

Well, the question now is: **Am I missing something here?** Is there something(like a book) somewhere where I can read about more of this kind of 'tricks' you can do to write same things in different ways?

Comment: You are on the right track!  Javascript is an incredibly flexible language that allows you to implement things in many different ways.  It seems to me you understand what you have posted above perfectly; you aren't missing anything other than what you have not yet explored.

Comment: not sure why everyone wants to make javascript object oriented. it's mostly a functional language. javascript is not java.

Comment: It's worth noting that you're creating something like a class that is only used once by calling new on an immediately invoked anonymous function. If anything it's an anit-pattern.
Speaking of anti-patterns, I believe what you may be looking for is a book on design patterns. These are generally the accepted ways you would do something in a language. Here's what I think is probably the most popular one: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript

Comment: Its just a class, right? what is "usual" javascript because classes are first class citizens in es6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to explore [prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) in JavaScript.  Here's an example of what you seem to want to do:

```js
function Car(make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage, started, start) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.color = color;
  this.passengers = passengers;
  this.convertible = convertible;
  this.mileage = mileage;
  this.started = started;
  this.start = start;
  this.func = function() {
    this.started = true;
  };
}

var chevy = new Car("Chevy", "Bel Air", 1957, "blue", 2, false, 1021, false);

console.log(chevy);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var myObj = {
  init: function(){
    this.methodOne();
    this.methodTwo();
  },

  propOne: 1,
  propTwo: 2,

  methodOne: function(){
    console.log(this.propOne + this.propTwo);
  },

  methodTwo: function(){
    console.log(this.propOne - this.propTwo);
  }
}
myObj.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you know what you're doing already .. so I won't go too far into depth.  I think object literals are bad form personally, mainly for two reasons:

1) It is not immediately apparent that that object literal is a type.  Some future engineer or yourself even, may come back and be like // ?

2) It'll be slower, because you're not defining the object definition up front, but rather each time you create one.  It has to create a new property with stuff.  If you define things up front, you define it once on prototype, and you're basically done with it.  V8 optimizes against prototype, so you get [substantial performance gains](https://medium.com/@tverwaes/setting-up-prototypes-in-v8-ec9c9491dfe2) for free.

I'll give you an example that's ES3 (except for Object.create).  It's more writing, but the format works well for real compilers (such as closure compiler).

You can use es6 "class" too of course, but there is a tiny overhead for validating that the function is not used without a this context.

```
// ctor
function MyClass(a, b, c) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
  console.log(this.methodOne());
}

// inheritance
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype);

// set the constructor property on the new prototype, for language conformity
MyClass.prototype.constructor = SuperClass;

/**
 * Example of what closure compiler can inline
 * @return {number}
 */
MyClass.prototype.methodTwo = function() {
   return 2;
};

MyClass.prototype.methodOne = function() {
};

// static
// closure compiler will move this up one scope to remove the object property read
MyClass.MY_STATIC_PROPERTY = 3;
```

This also keeps your definitions all in one place, rather that inlining.  Plus any object you create has the nice benefit of being show in the console with chrome with it's prototype name rather than Object.

new MyClass(1,2,3);